# Get tab bar items in xcode to show in image original color as soon as the view is loaded

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbaritem, loadview

Morning ya'll. I've designed a tab bar and managed to customise it with custom tab bar items but i can't figure out how you get the tab bar items to load in their original picture color when view is loaded. My code looks like this:

```
class GamePage: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBarItem.image = tabBarItem.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

             tabBarItem.selectedImage = tabBarItem.selectedImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    

}
```

which gives this outcome:
[greyed our tab bar items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLguq.png)

after clicking on the tab bar items i get the desired effect, but what i want is when the app launches and the first view is loaded to have the tab bar items in color like so:
[desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOtqF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set image rendering mode directly in Asset Catalog:

[image]